# ggplot2 facet labeller double subscript

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I'm plotting variables with double subscripts, and I would like to be able to keep the subscripts from getting mashed together in the facet strip text. Each label should display something like $\beta_{1, 12}$ instead of $\beta_112$. It should be enough to fix the following MWE.

```
d = data.frame(
  x = rnorm(6),
  y = rnorm(6), 
  z = rep(paste0("beta[", 1:3, "][", 12, "]"), each = 2))
library(ggplot2)
pl = ggplot(d) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~z, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

Comment: So there should be a comma inserted between the 1 and the 12 in B122? I think that is what you want, but you don't mention commas.

Comment: A comma would work, but so would any other delimiter that's both obvious and aesthetically right.

Comment: Doesn't look the best nor do you get the option to change the delimiter, but does accomplish the goal change `z` to  `z = rep(paste0("beta[list(", 1:3, ",", 12, ")]"), each = 2))` and continue as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)

d = data.frame(
  x = rnorm(6),
  y = rnorm(6), 
  z = rep(paste0("beta[", 1:3, "~~", 12, "]"), each = 2))
pl = ggplot(d) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~z, labeller = label_parsed)
pl
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. I prefer "~" instead of "~~" in line 6, but that's just my opinion. Where did you find out about that use of the tilde?

Comment: Thanks. Browse this to find more of this stuff: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Comment: So the facet "labeller" obeys `plotmath` rules. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the code for `label_parsed` (just enter the name without parens from the console) you can see how it builds this up using `parse`.