# how can I use special characters, superscripts or subscripts in a single label of faceted plots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like to add superscripts and / or subscripts to only a subset of strip text labels in a faceted plot layout like this one:

```
conc <- runif(nrow(iris), min = 5, max = 10)
df <- iris %>% mutate(mass_area = conc/Petal.Length*Sepal.Length)

melted <- reshape2::melt(df)
bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  ggtitle(mytitle) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free")
bp1
```

But `mass_area` should have a label in the form `lab = expression("Chl concentration" ~ (mu ~ g ~ " " ~ cm^{-2}))`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184982/ggplot2-facet-labeller-double-subscript) response is useful but labels all facets according to the same pattern. I need to label only one.

Comment: just a tiny tip for shortening your code, instead of `+ xlab("") + ylab("") ` you can use `labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)`. This is shorter, easier to read, and more importantly, using NULL you don't draw an empty placeholder, which you do with `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses the tidyverse packages. I've used `pivot_longer()` instead of `melt()` and
`case_when()` instead of `ifelse()` just to give you a second solution, but in the end it does the same because it is a vectorised *ifelse*.
This gives you the same result as stefans solution.

On a side note: I've corrected the expression, so there is no space in micrograms anymore.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
 
 conc <- runif(nrow(iris), min = 5, max = 10)
 df <- iris %>% mutate(mass_area = conc/Petal.Length*Sepal.Length)
 
 melted <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Species,
                               names_to = "variable") %>% 
    mutate(variable = case_when(variable == "mass_area" ~ paste0("Chl~concentration ~ (mu*g ~ cm^{-2})"),
                                TRUE ~ as.character(variable))
    )
 
 bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
    theme(
       legend.position = "bottom",
       plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free", label = "label_parsed")
 bp1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following the post you linked one option would be to use an `ifelse` to conditionally set the labels like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

set.seed(42)

conc <- runif(nrow(iris), min = 5, max = 10)
df <- iris %>% 
  mutate(mass_area = conc/Petal.Length*Sepal.Length)

melted <- reshape2::melt(df) %>% 
  mutate(variable = ifelse(variable == "mass_area",
                           paste0("Chl~concentration ~ (mu ~ g ~ cm^{-2})"), 
                           paste0(variable)))

#> Using Species as id variables

bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  ggtitle("mytitle") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free", labeller = label_parsed)
bp1
```

[image]